# How to POST, PUT and DELETE from Backbone app to Rails app on different subdomains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, put

Which is the best way to  POST, PUT and DELETE from Backbone app to Rails app on different subdomains?

I have tried to fetch some data with Backbone from the Rails app and it works.
I have tried to save new content with Backbone to Rails app.

I have real problems with PUT (updating a created model in database).
I don't know why, but when I do in my backbone app something like:
book.save()

And the book is a model that already exists on the database; instead of sending a PUT petition to the Rails APP, it is sending an OPTIONS petition, and without the data.

Ideally, I want to send a PUT petition from the Backbone app to the Rails app so that I can do something like this in my Rails app:

Book.update_attributes params[:book]

The Rails App and the Backbone app are on different subdomains on the same top-level domain.

Answer (score 1):

For methods that are not post or get, the client will send an OPTIONS request to determine what is allowed cross domain.
You'll need two things.
You'll need a way to respond with the correct response headers to tell the client that cross domain is ok. I create an after_filter in my ApplicationController since my cross domain needs are system wide.

```
after_filter :allow_cross_domain

def allow_cross_domain
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = request.env['HTTP_ORIGIN']
  headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"] = "*"
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "PUT, OPTIONS, GET, DELETE, POST"
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,x-requested-with,Content-Type'
  headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = 1728000
end
```

Next you need to handle the options request
In your routes.rb

```
match "*options", controller: "application", action: "options", constraints: { method: "OPTIONS" }
```

and in the controller that will handler the request (ApplicationController for me)

```
def options
  allow_cross_domain
  render :text => "", :layout => false
end
```

Comment: Unfortunally, I have tried this way and for any reason, I don't get params in options action. The exact routes.rb line is: match '/books.(:format)/:id', :controller => 'books', :action => 'options', :constraints => {:method => 'OPTIONS'} And in my books_controller I have: def options set_access_control_headers debugger 1 respond_to do |format| format.json {head :ok} end end The debugger returns: {"format"=>"json", "action"=>"options", "id"=>"6", "controller"=>"books"} But I have updated the title in Backbone and this params is not here. Thanks for your help

Comment: there will be two requests from backbone for cross domain. The first is the OPTIONS request. The rails app won't do anything except respond with the proper headers that tell the client what it is allowed to do. The client will then send the original PUT request. That's where you do the normal resource handling and update your book.